# Xcode Visual Storyboard issue with Nav Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

[Previous description deleted]

Let's try again.  I am using Xcode's Visual Storyboard.  I'm using a Navigation Controller Scene, which is linked to a View Controller Scene, which is then linked to 3 separate View Controller Scenes via buttons.

When I highlight the first View Controller Scene and enable the Assistant Editor, I am able to make changes to ViewController.h or .m in the adjacent window.

**Heart of the Problem:**
When I select any one of the 3 separate View Controller Scenes, my Assistant Editor shows "@interface UIViewController.h" when I was expecting ViewController.h or .m .  What's more, I can't make any changes as an error pops up "This content is locked for editing".

Be gentle, I'm new.  I'm sure I'm just missing something small.

---

**Solved, thanks to Douglas in the comments**

Comment: Without seeing the code I can't help you.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'm very visual, so I tried to describe what I was "seeing" in the visual interface.  Let me edit the above and add the code.

Comment: In each of your 3 view controllers, have you changed their class?  Each one needs a specific .h and .m file.  If you don't define one, you can't change or edit anything.  Let us know how it works out!

Comment: This!  I think you nailed my problem.  Using this information to solve now.

Comment: Confirmed Douglas.  This was exactly what my problem was.  A giant THANK YOU!

Comment: AWESOME!  I have added my comment as an answer so you can accept.  Thanks.  And I am glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each of your 3 view controllers, have you changed their class? Each one needs a specific .h and .m file. If you don't define one, you can't change or edit anything. Let us know how it works out!